# How to disable apache2 if systemctl disable fails due to "update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for apache2"?

Tags: apache2, systemd

If I disable the `systemd` unit `apache2` as usual with `systemctl disable` I get the following failure for `apache2` on Ubuntu 19.04:

```
> sudo systemctl disable apache2
Synchronizing state of apache2.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable apache2
update-rc.d: error: cannot find a LSB script for apache2
```

After a reboot the unit is started, so the disabling has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from the software updater to the other software tab. mark canonicals. Then turn it off. Switch to the terminal.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade apache2* -y
systemctl status apache2.service
```

Apache will work.